# Update Function To handle Multiple Documents In CouchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I am trying to write a save function which creates multiple documents in couchdb. I am using update function to do that. In my update function I want to get a specific value (highest number) from a set of documents to generate a new value for the new document. My question is how can i do that, get the value from other documents in a update function? for this I am not passing any document id or reference of the other documents to the update function. I just have map reduce function which emits the that specific value from other document. Is there any method or technique to get what i want? Please give me your suggestions and thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you only have the doc and request that were passed in.